# What's the fastest way to level up buddies without bringing them on quests?

Tags: monster-hunter-rise

Palicoes and palamutes (aka buddies) are used for a variety of things, including trading via the Argosy. There are several skill for buddies to use when trading, but they all have  a level requirement. Due to this, I'd like to level up my buddies as quickly as possible. However, I only like bringing my "original" buddies along with me on  quests (I named them both after IRL pets, so I just can't see the look of rejection in their eyes when I leave them behind while I go off killing monsters without them).

Due to all of the above, I'm trying to figure out what's the fastest way to level up my buddies, *without* bringing them on quests. I suspect it's sending them along on meowcenaries quests, but I haven't been paying close enough attention to my buddy levels to  be sure. Even if meowcenries is the fastest, I'm forced to wonder if factors such as the type of quests they're sent on will make a difference in the amount of experience they gain.

**What's the fastest  non-quest way to level  up my buddies?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's 3 methods of off-hunt training for buddies. Argosy, Meowcenaries, and the Dojo. All three methods level up buddies, but by far the most effective is the Dojo.

When assigning buddies to the dojo, before you begin you can use a laginapple to max out both the duration and gains they receive. after 10 hunts, return to the dojo and get the level ups.

A breakdown on exp per training activity:

- Argosy - Every quest finished any buddy set to trade will get a very small exp bump, along with the trade items collected (it takes a full round of 10 to get any reasonable level gain). Use this method only on already high level buddies for resources.
- Meowcenaries - a small exp bump every quest completed (if you recall them early), resulting in a medium-ish boost (1-3 levels) on completion. Use this method on mid-level buddies, for a balance of loot and exp
- Dojo - Once all ten boosted rounds complete, all 5 buddies receive a massive exp gain (close to 5 or 6 levels). Use this method for low levels, to bring them up to speed.

So, since Meowcenaries completes in 4, but Dojo takes 10. it may even out a little bit, but the dojo still takes the cake.

Disclaimer: this was tested with low level buddies, higher level ones need more exp to scale so they probably wont level as quickly... in any method.

Comment: I literally never realized before the buddy dojo wasn't just the name of the place you hire buddies from. I never noticed you could do training.